# How to filter a GraphQL query content using a specific value inside the content?

Tags: graphql, gatsby

How do I filter a GraphQL query content using a specific value inside the content data. For example I have contents received as a result of the following GraphQL query.

> ```
> query MyQuery {
>   allPages {
>     edges {
>       node {
>         content
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

From the above query I have received contents as follows. I'm trying to filter out the result using the "Type" Value (Veg/Fruit). How can I filter out the veg contents to display only Fruit content.

> ```
> {
>   "node": {
>     "content": [
>       {
>         "type": "Fruit",
>         "value": {
>           "Text": "Orange"
>         }
>       },
>       {
>         "type": "Fruit",
>         "value": {
>           "Text": "Apple"
>         }
>       }
>     ]
>   }
> },
> {
>   "node": {
>     "content": [
>       { 
>         "type": "Veg",
>         "value": {
>           "Text": "Broccoli"
>         }
>       },
>       {
>         "type": "Veg",
>         "value": {
>           "Text": "Lettuce"
>         }
>       }
>     ]
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Use [GraphQL filters](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/graphql-reference/#filter):

```
query MyQuery(filter: { content: { type: { eq: "Fruit" } } }) {
  allPages {
    edges {
      node {
        content
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*Note: I'm assuming, based on your question, that `type` is a property inside `content`. Adapt it to your needs if not. Using the `localhost:8000/___graphql` may help you to create a proper GraphQL query within filters.*

If you want to create different queries for each type of data you have, you can alias them like:

```
query MyQuery {
  fruit: allPages (filter: { content: { type: { eq: "Fruit" } } }) {
    edges {
      node {
        content
      }
    }
  }
  vegetables: allPages (filter: { content: { type: { eq: "Veg" } } }) {
    edges {
      node {
        content
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Your data, in this case, will be inside `props.data.fruit` or `props.data.vegetables`.

Comment: I will test this approach and will post the status here .. thanks @Ferran